# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32') error

Tags: python, deep-learning, valueerror

how can i solve this `ValueError`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.30,random_state=10)

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

output :

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

Comment: I have already used this code on another dataset. That time no error

Comment: Did you check the data for Nan? Fill in missing values?

Comment: try using float64 dtype. The error message itself is very clear in the sense that something in the data is getting too big numerically, or is already a NaN

Comment: Thank You . paritosh. I got it.

Comment: Thank you @sharan